# How would you use the tidyverse to calculate the Number of Next Out Winners from past performances

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr

Next out Winners are race entrants that are in a particular race together (RaceA), after that race each of the race entrants runs in another race, RaceB(i). RaceB(i) represents the next race that each competitor from RaceA raced in next. RaceB(i) can be different or the same for each of the runners (no requirement that its the same race.)

Next Out Winners is a metric for RaceA (and other races) that reflects the number of runners that won their RaceB(i) within some specified timeframe, say 90 days. Races run after the specified timeframe are not included when deriving Next Out Winners.

My question is how would one go about calculating this with the tidyverse? I assume that purrr function will play a prominent role.

**Problem-solving logic**:
key inputs: races, dates, runners and finishing positions.
data: data frame of races sorted in ascending order that is date, race_number and runners.

**key function**(s): map2_xxx or pmap function that sums/counts for all horses in the subject race that race again within 90 days in the future and won (finish =1).

**Questions**: How will our function know to only review 1 next out race for each horse). Going through every race in the data frame would be highly inefficient. I've created a small sample data frame and included it in a reprex. I'm continuing to work on this, but would welcome any assistance or suggestions anyone has to offer.

**Reprex**:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(lubridate)
library(reprex)
#> Warning: package 'reprex' was built under R version 3.5.3

jdiff <- function(x, y, t="equal", i=0, j=0){
  case_when(
    t == 'equal'~ if_else(x ==y,1L,0L),
    t == 'rng' ~ if_else(x >= y-i & x <= y+j,1L,0L),
    TRUE ~ 0L
  )

}

df<-tibble(runner=c("D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","D.Wottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","C.Hottle","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt","JJ.Watt"),
           race_number=c(6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1,6,5,4,3,2,1),
           race_venue=c("xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx","xyx"),
           race_date=c(ymd('20170625'),ymd('20170524'),ymd('20170420'),ymd('20170329'),ymd('20170308'),ymd('20170215'),ymd('20170625'),ymd('20170524'),ymd('20170410'),ymd('20170329'),ymd('20170304'),ymd('20170215'),ymd('20170615'),ymd('20170524'),ymd('20170428'),ymd('20170329'),ymd('20170301'),ymd('20170225')),
           distance=c(1400L,1400L,1600L,1400L,1500L,1400L,1400L,1400L,1600L,1400L,1500L,1400L,1400L,1400L,1600L,1400L,1500L,1400L),
           finish=c(1L,2L,2L,1L,2L,3L,2L,3L,3L,2L,1L,1L,3L,1L,1L,3L,3L,2L)
           ) %>% 
  arrange(race_date, race_number, finish) %>% 
  # Calculation here to add Next out winner for each Race
  #
  mutate(next_out_winners = 0) %>% 
  group_by(race_date, race_number)

  #group by races to show the next out winner for each race
  #group_by(race_dte, race_number)


print(df,36)
#> # A tibble: 18 x 7
#> # Groups:   race_date, race_number [12]
#>    runner   race_number race_venue race_date  distance finish next_out_winners
#>    <chr>          <dbl> <chr>      <date>        <int>  <int>            <dbl>
#>  1 C.Hottle           1 xyx        2017-02-15     1400      1                0
#>  2 D.Wottle           1 xyx        2017-02-15     1400      3                0
#>  3 JJ.Watt            1 xyx        2017-02-25     1400      2                0
#>  4 JJ.Watt            2 xyx        2017-03-01     1500      3                0
#>  5 C.Hottle           2 xyx        2017-03-04     1500      1                0
#>  6 D.Wottle           2 xyx        2017-03-08     1500      2                0
#>  7 D.Wottle           3 xyx        2017-03-29     1400      1                0
#>  8 C.Hottle           3 xyx        2017-03-29     1400      2                0
#>  9 JJ.Watt            3 xyx        2017-03-29     1400      3                0
#> 10 C.Hottle           4 xyx        2017-04-10     1600      3                0
#> 11 D.Wottle           4 xyx        2017-04-20     1600      2                0
#> 12 JJ.Watt            4 xyx        2017-04-28     1600      1                0
#> 13 JJ.Watt            5 xyx        2017-05-24     1400      1                0
#> 14 D.Wottle           5 xyx        2017-05-24     1400      2                0
#> 15 C.Hottle           5 xyx        2017-05-24     1400      3                0
#> 16 JJ.Watt            6 xyx        2017-06-15     1400      3                0
#> 17 D.Wottle           6 xyx        2017-06-25     1400      1                0
#> 18 C.Hottle           6 xyx        2017-06-25     1400      2                0
```

<sup>Created on 2020-05-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Desired Output (calculated by hand)

[image]

Comment: @RonakShah I've added the desired output. Thanks. This assumes the window for the next out race is 90 days.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't use a `map` function - I used `lead`

```
nextouts <- df %>% 
    # These are clutter
  select(- race_venue, -distance) %>% 
  arrange(runner, race_date) %>% 
  group_by(runner) %>% 
    # Use 'lead' to compare this race to the next one.
  mutate(next_finish = lead(finish, default= 0),
         next_date = lead(race_date, default = NA),
         is_next_out_win =
           (next_finish == 1 & next_date - race_date <= 90)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Result looks good so far

```
# A tibble: 18 x 7
   runner   race_number race_date  finish next_finish next_date  is_next_out_win
   <chr>          <dbl> <date>      <int>       <dbl> <date>     <lgl>          
 1 C.Hottle           1 2017-02-15      1           1 2017-03-04 TRUE           
 2 C.Hottle           2 2017-03-04      1           2 2017-03-29 FALSE          
 3 C.Hottle           3 2017-03-29      2           3 2017-04-10 FALSE          
 4 C.Hottle           4 2017-04-10      3           3 2017-05-24 FALSE          
 5 C.Hottle           5 2017-05-24      3           2 2017-06-25 FALSE          
 6 C.Hottle           6 2017-06-25      2           0 NA         FALSE          
 7 D.Wottle           1 2017-02-15      3           2 2017-03-08 FALSE          
 8 D.Wottle           2 2017-03-08      2           1 2017-03-29 TRUE           
 9 D.Wottle           3 2017-03-29      1           2 2017-04-20 FALSE          
10 D.Wottle           4 2017-04-20      2           2 2017-05-24 FALSE          
11 D.Wottle           5 2017-05-24      2           1 2017-06-25 TRUE           
12 D.Wottle           6 2017-06-25      1           0 NA         FALSE          
13 JJ.Watt            1 2017-02-25      2           3 2017-03-01 FALSE          
14 JJ.Watt            2 2017-03-01      3           3 2017-03-29 FALSE          
15 JJ.Watt            3 2017-03-29      3           1 2017-04-28 TRUE           
16 JJ.Watt            4 2017-04-28      1           1 2017-05-24 TRUE           
17 JJ.Watt            5 2017-05-24      1           3 2017-06-15 FALSE          
18 JJ.Watt            6 2017-06-15      3           0 NA         FALSE
```

Look at the results by race:

```
nextoutsR <- nextouts %>% 
  arrange(race_number)

# A tibble: 18 x 7
   runner   race_number race_date  finish next_finish next_date  is_next_out_win
   <chr>          <dbl> <date>      <int>       <dbl> <date>     <lgl>          
 1 C.Hottle           1 2017-02-15      1           1 2017-03-04 TRUE           
 2 D.Wottle           1 2017-02-15      3           2 2017-03-08 FALSE          
 3 JJ.Watt            1 2017-02-25      2           3 2017-03-01 FALSE          
 4 C.Hottle           2 2017-03-04      1           2 2017-03-29 FALSE          
 5 D.Wottle           2 2017-03-08      2           1 2017-03-29 TRUE           
 6 JJ.Watt            2 2017-03-01      3           3 2017-03-29 FALSE          
 7 C.Hottle           3 2017-03-29      2           3 2017-04-10 FALSE          
 8 D.Wottle           3 2017-03-29      1           2 2017-04-20 FALSE          
 9 JJ.Watt            3 2017-03-29      3           1 2017-04-28 TRUE           
10 C.Hottle           4 2017-04-10      3           3 2017-05-24 FALSE          
11 D.Wottle           4 2017-04-20      2           2 2017-05-24 FALSE          
12 JJ.Watt            4 2017-04-28      1           1 2017-05-24 TRUE           
13 C.Hottle           5 2017-05-24      3           2 2017-06-25 FALSE          
14 D.Wottle           5 2017-05-24      2           1 2017-06-25 TRUE           
15 JJ.Watt            5 2017-05-24      1           3 2017-06-15 FALSE          
16 C.Hottle           6 2017-06-25      2           0 NA         FALSE          
17 D.Wottle           6 2017-06-25      1           0 NA         FALSE          
18 JJ.Watt            6 2017-06-15      3           0 NA         FALSE
```

Looks like there's one next-out-winner in each race (except the last.)  Which makes sense, since there's only 3 horses and the run in every race.

Let's sum it up.  Remember, you can sum TRUE, FALSE as thought they were 1,0.

```
nextOutWinsInRace <- nextouts %>% 
  group_by(race_number) %>% 
  summarise(nextOutWinCount = sum(is_next_out_win))

R> nextOutWinsInRace
# A tibble: 6 x 2
  race_number nextOutWinCount
        <dbl>           <int>
1           1               1
2           2               1
3           3               1
4           4               1
5           5               1
6           6               0
```

Call it a wrap.

Comment: that's very impressive.  Smart move creating the column of next races.  I spent a couple  of hours work on this and didn't come up with that.  Thanks.

Comment: Thank you. Did my answer solve your problem? (hint)

Comment: I want to see how it performs against a real data set.